# Programmatically update alt tag on image field

Tags: 8, media

I have a Drupal 8 site with a content type that has an image field. For existing nodes of this type, most have image files, but none have alt tags.

I am writing an update hook where I want to set the alt tag value for existing nodes. However, I have not been able to figure out how, nor find documentation.

This is what I have:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','sfa_social_post')->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
  $node->field_sfa_image_file->alt = 'Image for ' . $node->getTitle();
}
```

Where `field_sfa_image_file` is the name of the image field.

When I re-loop through the nodes, I get back the value that I set.

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','sfa_social_post')->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
  drush_print('Title: ' . $node->getTitle());
  drush_print('Alt: ' . $node->field_sfa_image_file->alt);
}
```

Which gives me

```
Title: Instagram Post ID: 1917569620391415985_3017827348
Alt: Image for Instagram Post ID: 1917569620391415985_3017827348
Title: Instagram Post ID: 1917562614863492125_3017827348
Alt: Image for Instagram Post ID: 1917562614863492125_3017827348
```

So all seems good. However, when I navigate to nodes, I don't see my alt text:

[image]

How do I set the alt tag for an existing image field?

Comment: Have you saved the nodes (`$node->save()`)?

Comment: ` $node->field_image->alt = 'some alt';` works for me, i have tested it in `hook_node_presave`, i think you miss just `$node->save()` as @Clive said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @clive suggested use `$node->save();`. Without node saving, alt of the image will not show up in the edit form.

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','sfa_social_post')->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->field_sfa_image_file->alt = 'Image for ' . $node->getTitle();
  $node->save();
}
```